# Passing a String to other activity did not work

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

So I have a textEdit field in MainActivity2. And I will pass the String of it to MainActivity8. You go to MainActivity8 if you click a Button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2activity);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity8.class);

            EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String Link1 = et1.getText().toString();

            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);
            String Kat1 = et.getText().toString();


            if (Link1.matches("") || Kat1.matches("")){
                et.setHintTextColor(RED);
                et1.setHintTextColor(RED);
            }
            else {
                startActivity(i);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity8.class);
            intent.putExtra("Kate1", Kat1);
        }
    });
```

And MainActivity8 looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity8 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main8);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Kategorie1 = intent.getExtras().getString("Kategorie1");

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. textView2);
    tv.setText(Kategorie1);


}
```

}

So everytime when I click the Button my App is crashing. And i don't know whats wrong. I get this from the Android Monitor:

12-30 11:45:29.046 29591-29591/com.example.luca.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.luca.myapplication, PID: 29591
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.luca.myapplication/com.example.luca.myapplication.MainActivity8}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Can you give me a tip whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2activity);

((Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String Link1 = et1.getText().toString();

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);
        String Kat1 = et.getText().toString();


        if (Link1.matches("") || Kat1.matches("")){
            et.setHintTextColor(RED);
            et1.setHintTextColor(RED);
        }
        else {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity8.class);
        intent.putExtra("Kate1", Kat1);
            startActivity(intent );
        }


    }
});
```

and MainActivity8.class

```
  public class MainActivity8 extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main8);

String Kategorie1 =getIntent().getStringExtra("Kate1");

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. textView2);
tv.setText(Kategorie1);
}
}
```

You start intent i but not put extra value in intent i you put value Intent "intent".

Answer (score 2):

at first you are send your data using "Kate1" keyword

```
intent.putExtra("Kate1", Kat1);
```

and fetching data using key "Kategorie1" which is different

change

```
intent.getExtras().getString("Kategorie1");
```

to

```
intent.getExtras().getString("Kate1");
```

Comment: Hey I changed it but it's still the same thing it didn't work.

Comment: Also, he is starting the activity with the intent `i`: `startActivity(i);`, but puts the data in the `intent`.

Comment: check your startActivity method it should be after intent this line " Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity8.class);
            intent.putExtra("Kate1", Kat1);" startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 0):

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra("your putString value"));
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

your key is "Kate1" and on another activity you used "Kategorie1".

put same key brother.

Answer (score 0):

check null before getString

```
  Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
  if (bundle!= null) {
  link = bundle.getString("Kate1");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the intent with which you are starting the activity ,in that intent's bundle you are not adding the string to be sent.

from your code,you are creating an intent i like this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity8.class);
```

and starting the activity using that intent "i" , but you are not putting the string in that intent object.

so just your proper code should be like shown below :

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity8.class);

                EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String Link1 = et1.getText().toString();

                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);
                String Kat1 = et.getText().toString();


                if (Link1.matches("") || Kat1.matches("")){
                    et.setHintTextColor(RED);
                    et1.setHintTextColor(RED);
                }
                else {
                    i.putExtra("Kate1",Kat1);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                //remove this intent,as not required
            }
        });
```

and in the MainActivity8 , try to get the string with the same key **Kate1**

```
intent.getExtras().getString("Kate1");
```